# Will it be memory leak here?

Tags: c, pebble-sdk

I'm coding for pebble and it doesn't allow to use `free()`

I want to get current time and this works. But I'm not sure if it's memory safe. I mean `ts` - is a pointer and I think it will need to be free() after use

```
struct tm *ts;
  time_t timestamp = time(NULL);
  ts = localtime(&timestamp);
```

Will it be memory leak here? If yes, how to change the code so it will not be any leaks?

Comment: You haven't called malloc. So you shouldn't need to call free

Comment: @user1281385: Ever heard of `realloc()`? THere are plenty functions returning dynamic memory, though few in the C standard library.

Comment: It needs to have a pointer from malloc or calloc first though

Comment: This is about the Pebble SDK which [doesn't even have `malloc`/`realloc`/`free`](https://developer.getpebble.com/1/04_MoreResources/01_FAQ/).

Comment: @DarkDust The current Pebble SDK actually does have [malloc and free](https://developer.getpebble.com/2/api-reference/group___standard_memory.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no leak.

The function returns a pointer to an internal object, which hold the correct data untul the next call to localtime().

Comment: Check out [description of `localtime`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/localtime/?kw=localtime) for reference.

Comment: Which means it is not multithreading-safe, signal-safe or reentrant.

Comment: @Deduplicator: the Pebble doesn't have threads, signals or things like that. This isn't a full-fledged POSIX environment.

Comment: @DarkDust Not even interrupts?

Comment: PebbleOS does indeed have interrupts and threads - just your app is limited to a single thread, and reentrancy is handled for you.